# How does concurrency work with Hibernate/SQL?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, concurrency, thread-safety

So,

I'm writing a JavaFX based desktop application. The software isn't intended for real world use and the time frame to construct it is extremely limited, so rather than constructing a full on backend, we intend to do the backend type stuff in the program itself.

In other words, instead of connecting to a backend, we are going to just connect directly to the database. We would expect to have several instances of this software running at any given time though, which is cause for concern.

From what I understand, Hibernate makes heavy use of caching database data.

What happens if say, the program gets some data from the database, does some work, and updates the database row. In the meantime, another instance of the application has gone in and grabbed a copy of the data as well to do it's own calculations on it. By the time the second instance commits it's data to the database, of course the data will be out of date.

How do I address such a situation using Hibernate?

Comment: It is about optimistic locking in Hibernate. In short it is about either version column or timestamp column in database. When second instance tries to update record in DB with outdated "version" hibernate throws exception about it. Then usually UI tier asks user to refersh data and try again... something like that...

Comment: You should clarify what your goal is. Do you want to prevent the caching, or synchronizing the caches? Hint: synchronizing the caches is hard.